# How to put a alert error message in django form?

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms

I have actually followed [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html) tutorial to perform ajax request on error in form field.

Then I performed the following:

My models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user                = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="Company_Owner",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    books_begining_from = models.DateField(default=datetime.date(2018,4,1), blank=False)
    gst_enabled         = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    composite_enable    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My views:

```
def validate_gst_billing(request):

    data = {
        'is_enable' : Company.objects.filter(gst_enabled = False,composite_enable = True)
    }
    if data['is_enable']:
        data['error_message'] = 'To enable composite billing GST should be enabled'
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

In my html:

```
    <script>
    $("#id_composite_enable").change(function () {
      var form = $(this).closest("form");
      $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("data-validate-gst-billing-url"),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.is_enable) {
            alert(data.error_message);
          }
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
```

I want to throw an `error message` to the users as an alert if they try to `submit` a form with the `gst_enable` field set to `False` and the `composite_enable` field set to `True`.

Any idea what is wrong in my code?

Thank you

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use error method in ajax like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/list',
    success: function(data , textStatus ,jqXHR){
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(textStatus)
        console.log(errorThrown)
    }
});
```

you can right click in your page select inspect element and in the console tab see your console log

Comment: I want an error message to validate a certain field in my form....You can see the tutorial I have given above...

Comment: hi again, i read this tutorial and done completely , I want to create your project in my working directory but i dont have your complete code.

I study again your question and i think your url is mistake and I prefer you should try print your url like this code :
console.log(form.attr("data-validate-gst-billing-url"))
if ajax side

and enter this url in browser url and see your json result, if worked change this url fetch code.

Answer (score 0):

For what I see, you are not setting any boolean on 'is_enable'. Add .exists() method to the queryset to get a boolean.

```
def validate_gst_billing(request):

    data = {
        'is_enable' : Company.objects.filter(gst_enabled=False, composite_enable=True).exists()
    }
    if data['is_enable']:
        data['error_message'] = 'To enable composite billing GST should be enabled'
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: The `if` condition inside the javascript I wrote is not working even if the condition satisfies...Can you tell me why?

Comment: What does data.is_enable is showing? (in js, do a console.log()) to display it. You should also add an error method to your ajax method to handle possible errors.

Comment: Its not displaying anything in the console but if I do a `console.log()` outside `if` statement its displaying the output

Comment: which outpout are you getting? Maybe you need to do a if(data['is_enable'])?